# Imported CA certificate to Firefox Browser not working

Tags: tls, certificate, openssl

I created Certificate Authority (CA) according to [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSSL) using openssl. After creating a certificate for Apache2 and adding to certificate to it, I want to import it in Firefox. In the end of document, there is some information for adding CA certificate to Browser. Before that I should create  `PKCS#12 certificate` using follwoing commands:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out      mycert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert.pfx -in mycert.pem -name "Certificate for Whatever"
```

to create pfx file. But the problems is how this could **relates** to CA certification? For example, in the document the author generated a file called `cacert.pem` for CA certification and a file called `cakey.pem` for server private key. What is usage of the file`mycert.pem`?

As another note, after I runs following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out      mycert.pem
```

I asked for entering Common Name information (like city, organization, ...). I entered some information (randomly) to the questions and finally after executing second command I produced `mycert.pfx` file and imported it to Firefox (as described in the end of document). But it does not recognized the .pfx file and nothing has been imported!

After that I decide to import `cacert.pem` and the file successfully added to list of trusted authorities:

[image]

But after importing certificate to Firefox and restarting it, When I request the page, I got `This Connection is Untrusted` page (meaning Firefox does not trust in my CA certificate) in the response. Where is the problem?

**Updates**:
I added following image from my Firefox exception certificate view:

[image]

Comment: Does the Common Name matches the name you type in the browser? I see you are on "http://localhost" did you issued a certificate for "localhost" as well?

Comment: @M'vy can I add mousaviserver.com (Common name for apache sever certificate) to my hosts file in Windows and try it again?

Comment: Just to clarify, you've also imported the certificate on the Windows machine?

Comment: @raz before I check it, can you suggest me which one I should add to my windows (and browser)? mycert.pfx or cacert.pem?

Comment: I don't see where you generated cacert.pem.  I would go with mycert.pem.  .pem or .pfx is just the format of the certificate.  Firefox only supports a few and .pfx isn't one of them.

Comment: @M'vy your right! I tried Common Name and it works fine. Can you add your comment as answer so I can make it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

> openssl req -x509 [...]
>   to create pfx file. But the problems is how this could relates to CA certification?

Not at all. The "-x509" parameter triggers generation of a SELF SIGNED certificate. I.E. it is not signed by your CA.

See https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html